# AngularJS UI Router - Nested state with individual views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a menu on my website, where the items have an active state. The default state is `areas`, then I can navigate through my website changing states.

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="areas">
        <span>Areas</span>
    </a>
</li>

.state('areas', {
    url: '/areas',
    templateUrl : 'templates/areas.html',
    controller  : 'AreaCtrl'
})
```

In my `areas.html` template, I have a list, with items which can be clicked...:

```
<li ng-repeat="area in areas" ui-sref="areas.city({areaId: area.area_id, areaName: area.name})">
```

Now when one of these is clicked, I need to keep the active state on my menu. So the only way of doing this is via nested states...

```
.state('areas.city', {
    url: "/:areaId/:areaName",
    templateUrl: 'dist/templates/cities.html',
    controller: 'CityCtrl'
})
```

However the problem is, my `cities.html` needs to be a totally new view (in place of where `areas.html` is), which isn't nested within `areas` (so I don't have a `<ui-view>` within `areas.html`).

I can, just not nest the view, so the state is `.state('city'`, but then I lose the `active` state on the menu.

Any clue how I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the state in the main menu as like below

```
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('area') || $state.includes('areas.city')}">
    <a ui-sref="areas">
        <span>Areas</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Also, please apply the $state into $rootScope. So that you can access $state in any views.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
```